# Postgresql extended statistics for better join estimates

Tags: postgresql

Hi I got two tables in Postgresql that looks something like this(highly simplified):

```sql
create table main_table
(
    main_table_id         varchar(255) not null
        primary key,
    main_table_type       varchar(255)
);

create table join_table
(
    main_table_id   varchar(255) not null
        constraint fk_main_table_id
            references main_table,
    foreign_table_id           bigint       not null
        constraint fk_foreign_table_id
            references foreign_table
);
```

Number of foreign ids in the join table is highly dependant on main_table_type. Some types are 1:1 but others can have hundreds of rows in the join table. This is causing big underestimates or overestimates when joining those tables.

Is there a way to create extended statistics to improve this? I tried adding the type column to the join table and creating ndistinct statistics on `main_table_id` and the `main_table_type` but unfortunately that did not help.

The join table has around 500K rows.

Postgresql version is 15.

Comment: I am afraid that extended statistics won't help. I don't think you can improve that estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, generating extended statistics in PostgreSQL can aid in query preparation, as in your case with different cardinalities in the join table. But your strategy needs to be all-encompassing. It is not enough to just add the `type` column to the join table and get unique statistics; to capture the combined distribution, think about generating multi-column statistics that contain both `main_table_id` and `main_table_type`. Additionally, make sure that you've executed `ANALYSE` on the `main_table` and the `join_table` in order to give PostgreSQL precise data distribution information. Query performance can also be improved by investigating materialised views, query optimisation, and PostgreSQL's cost parameters, as well as by indexing frequently used columns. Partitioning the `join_table` according to `main_table_type` could be very beneficial, depending on how complicated your workload is. To find the best strategy for your particular data and queries, try out these approaches, keep an eye on query performance, and examine query plans.

Hope this helps, do let me know if you need more assistance.